# How to Android partly color SVG image resource

Tags: android, svg

In my android view I want to make star rating.

I have stars `SVG` and need to change their color partly like this

[image: like this]

not full color, I have searched and there are only answers about *setColorFilter* , but **it's not resolve my problem**

Comment: u take directly `Ratingbar` why you take a SVG images ?

Answer (score 0):

you can not change color partially but one solution is you set different different images for example if user select half rating so you change image as half rating selection and accordingly change of user choice.